# REACT: How can you set a nested child's state

Tags: reactjs, state, react-props, setstate

I would like to set a child component's state (located two levels deep) from the parent component. Is there a way to do this so that the child component's state is updated as the parent's state updates?

Thanks!

Edit:

This is my structure:
Parent -> Child 1 -> Child 2

How can I access Parent's state from Child 2

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Redux? It would be the best, because as you have more children, it will be more difficult to manage the state in each of them